# How to import data ONLY from tables in another access database (accdb) file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have made some changes to the design of backend database which is being used by some clients. Now I need to replace the older backend database file with the new one, but at the same time import all the older records to the newer one too. The design changes are not major and no field names were changed. When I try to import tables from older to newer database through External Data->Access, it imports the complete tables instead of just their data. How do I import the data ONLY from older tables in older database to newer database? I tried to design a append query, but couldn't find a way to fetch data from a different database. I am using Access 2010 if it matters.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest creating code within your new FE file which creates the new tables, relationships, indexes and new fields on existing tables.  And runs any update queries required although it sounds like in your current situation there weren't any.

[Updating an Access Backend MDBs structure using VBA code](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/backendupdate.htm)
[The Compare'Em utility has made this process much easier.](http://home.gci.net/~mike-noel/CompareEM-LITE/CompareEM.htm)

I would suggest keeping a version number of the FE and BE in a table thus helping you to figure out when to run the code or not allow a new FE to be run against an old format BE.

Comment: I've NEVER done that. I just do the changes by hand. I open a document, and carefully write down each step that I need to take to make the changes. In general, schema changes in a production app should be VERY VERY RARE. If they aren't, you went into production prematurely.

Comment: David, I makes lots and lots of schema changes as I upgrade a product over the years.

Comment: I, on the other hand, do not. I have a half dozen apps that date from c. 1997-98, and most of them have had at least one or two schema changes, but I've always collected those together and done them as major upgrades. Mostly my reason is because it's so hard to coordinate front-end updates with the schema changes. I'd rather not implement interim schemas, or be forced to design my schema change to be backwardly compatible. This makes my life a lot easier. But then, I also am onsite at almost all my clients on a regular basis...